# Basic Python Question, Working with Function and List

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and learning Python over the web and I'm stuck on this problem.

The objective is to have a list of numbers and create a function that will evaluate that list of numbers and print out the matches and the position in the list the matches are found at.

I think I'm 90% there, but the function I wrote only prints out the first match it finds, then ends.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    list=[36, 36, 79, 96, 36, 91, 77, 33, 19, 3, 34, 70, 12, 12, 54, 98, 86, 11, 17, 17]

    def find(list,x):
        for i in range(len(list)):
            if x == i:
                print ("Found",x,"at position",i)

    find(list,12)
    find(list,91)
    find(list,80)
```

This correctly prints out:

"Found 12 at position 12", but fails to print the complete answer which is:

Found 12 at position 12
Found 12 at position 13
Found 91 at position 5

It appears the loop is ending prematurely, but I don't understand why.  I realize this is probably pretty basic stuff, but I appreciate your time and any advice.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be better suited to a general programming forum as it does not really relate to game development.

Comment: This would be better suited on stackoverflow.com, as it is not really related to game development.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are checking the **index** of the element, not the actual element itself. Substitute `list[i]` for `i` and it works, for:

```
list=[36, 36, 79, 96, 36, 91, 77, 33, 19, 3, 34, 70, 12, 12, 54, 98, 86, 11, 17, 17]

def find(list,x):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if x == list[i]:
            print ("Found",x,"at position",i)

find(list,12)
find(list,91)
find(list,80)
```

However, this isn't very idiomatic ("pythonic") code. Using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over a pairing of index/value, we can rewrite it as:

```
lst = [36, 36, 79, 96, 36, 91, 77, 33, 19, 3, 34, 70, 12, 12, 54, 98, 86, 11, 17, 17]

def find(lst, x):
    for i,value in enumerate(lst):
        if value == x:
            print("Found {0} at position {1}".format(value, i))

find(lst,12)
find(lst,91)
find(lst,80)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about enumerate.  Just starting this stuff.  Bookmarked that link!

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

This being said, you check if the current index (`i`) is equal to the desired number (`x`), so it will always return the same number as `x`.

Instead, you want to see **if the item in the list at the current index is equal to x**, like so: `if list[i] == x:`.

The index represent the current *position* that you're at, say first item, second, etc. You are looking for the *item* equal to `x`, so this is the nuance.

Good luck with the rest, and feel free to ask game related questions here, but make sure they are specifically about games! :)

Comment: Much appreciated.  The "class" I'm taking is about building games in Python, but it makes much more sense to post a question like this in the general forum.  Will do going forward.  Appreciate the advice!

Comment: @user30869 Feel free to come here for anything else game-related though! We love to help, although we just want the questions to go to the according site. :) Stackoverflow is a fantastic resource with incredibly fast feedback for anything about general programming.